# Handling url targeted PHP page with custom jQuery loaded content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

First I used `include('pageName.php');` for every page I wanted to load.

Now I decided to rewrite everything and to load a page in a `<div id="page_content"></div>` with the jQuery function: `$('#page_content').load(pageurl, {access:true});`

I hope this is the best practice. Because I want to reduce load time on my web application by not refreshing the whole website with all CSS and JS files but just to refresh content when clicked on a new page.

Currently I am using the following function to load pages into the division and to pushState to history:

```
//Dynload pages
        $("a[rel='dynload']").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).attr("page");
            var pageurl = "pages/" + page + ".php";
            $('#page_content').load(pageurl, {access:true});
            if(pageurl!=window.location){
                 window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',page);
            }
            //stop refreshing to the page given in
            return false;
            });
```

This works perfectly.
I have this button that triggers this function and gives for attribute `page="index_content"` . The function will load this page to the division and the state is being pushed into the history.

However. We get an url something like this: `https://mywebsite.com/index_content`
**The problem is**, when I load this specific URL into my browser I get : "Page not found" ofcourse, because it is trying to search for the index_content folder which does not exist.

Is there a way to check the url by my PHP/jQuery script and to load the correct page into the division? If not, how can I solve this for a generic case. 
When I add a new page, I want to spend no- to very less time on the pageswitcher function.

In that way I can also handle non-existing pages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Or are you trying to make it so that a single page that loads different content dynamically, is built so that the dynamic parts are linkable?

Comment: Exactly. It is one index.php which loads several pages in it. But you have to be able to get to a specific page directly through the URL.
First a page was accessable by entering something like https://mywebsite.com/?page=index_content Because my PHP handled the GET variable and included the page according to the GET. Hope you get it now.

Comment: Right, so you'd continue to follow that pattern, changing the value of page to whatever dynamic content should load.

Comment: I honestly dont know if this is the best practice to work this out.
If you take an AngularJS based web application you will also see this result, I try to replicate this with jQuery and PHP. 
Check out this example for instance and switch pages from Dashboard1 to Dashboard2. https://pixinvent.com/apex-angular-4-bootstrap-admin-template/demo-1/dashboard/dashboard2
If you manually go to the url that changes if you switch pages, it will automatically handle the right pages + menu.

Comment: You are trying to create a SPA (Single Page Application).  To answer if it is the "best practice" is really dependent upon your situation and your needs.  But it's a fairly common design practice now days.

Comment: @Taplar true, this is what Iam trying to achieve. Because everytime I switch to another page, the same objects like CSS stylesheets and JS files are being load into the page. They dont have to be reloaded

Comment: Right.  Which there are plenty of examples/frameworks available that offer information/implementation of this out of the box.  What exactly are you asking about?  If you are asking us how to implement a SPA then this question is too broad.

Comment: I have everything covered already. But my specific question is how do I adjust the good page content + menu according to the URL that is being load?
For example if I run my page https://mywebsite.com/index_content
It actually has to go to https://mywebsite.com/index.php and tell my jQuery or PHP that we have to load the "index_content" page. 
With PHP it was easy, just an GET variable. But right now I dont know how to handle.

Comment: Typically you would load the common part as part of your index.php, or whatever base page you have, and then another field on the url, be it apart of a query string or a #hash on the url, would direct the script to load the dynamic content that is needed.  If that parameter is not provided it would load whatever default content you desire. `https://example.com?page=aboutus` `https://example.com#aboutus` or something of that nature.

Comment: aah yes, with a hash it is definitely possible. But there is no way to do it with something like https://mywebsite.com/aboutus ? It looks neater

Comment: Not if you want to make a SPA using javascript.

Comment: Then this is the way to go. Probably going to use the hash. Thanks for all the help!